# Cant resolve DOM component SharedStylesHost

Tags: angular

I updated my app from 2.4 to 4.0.3. One error left which I am not able to fix on my own.

```
./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/shared_styles_host' in 'C:\solutions\projectx\src\app'
```

TypeScript Compiler tells in the Terminal:

```
[at-loader] ./src/app/app.component.ts:47:44
TS2304: Cannot find name 'SharedStylesHost'.
```

What am I doing wrong? Also on angular.io i don't find any hint.

EDIT: added app.component.ts

```
import {
    Component, ElementRef, NgZone, OnInit, Renderer2, ViewChild, 
    ViewEncapsulation
} from '@angular/core';
import { AppState } from './app.service';
import {
    Event as RouterEvent,
    NavigationCancel,
    NavigationEnd,
    NavigationError,
    NavigationStart,
    Router
} from '@angular/router';
import { DeviceDetectionService } from 'shared-signup';
import { ElementQueriesService } from 'shared-angular';
import { ELEMENT_QUERIES } from './shared-models/element-queries.const';
import { SharedStylesHost } from '@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/shared_styles_host';

const EQ: any = require('css-element-queries/src/ElementQueries');

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styleUrls: [
        './app.styles.scss'
    ],
    templateUrl: './app.template.html',
    providers: [
        ElementQueriesService
    ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('loadingElement')
    public loadingElement: ElementRef;

    public ELEMENT_QUERIES: ({ name: string, 'max-width': string } | { name: string, 'min-width': string })[];

    constructor(public appState: AppState,
            private _sharedStylesHost: SharedStylesHost,
            private _router: Router,
            private _ngZone: NgZone,
            private _renderer: Renderer2,
            private _elementQueriesService: ElementQueriesService) {

    this.ELEMENT_QUERIES = ELEMENT_QUERIES;

    _router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
        this._navigationInterceptor(event);
    });

    DeviceDetectionService.customMobileDetection = function () {
        return _elementQueriesService.hasSize(['small']);
    };

    /*
     ugly workaround to avoid initial layout problems with slow connections

     If the connection is slow and the files are not cached, the document.styleSheets.length property is smaller then 5, even if the onStylesAdded method is call (whyever).
     To avoid the problem, check the style length until it is bigger then five, then init the ElementQueries plugin.
     ToDo: find a better place to init ElementQueries, or build a simple service for it
     */
    const oldOnStylesAdded = (<any>_sharedStylesHost).onStylesAdded;
    let checkStyleLength = function () {
        (document.styleSheets.length < 5)
            ? setTimeout(checkStyleLength, 300)
            : EQ.init(true);
    };

    checkStyleLength();

    (<any>_sharedStylesHost).onStylesAdded = (additions: string[]) => {
        oldOnStylesAdded.apply(this._sharedStylesHost, [additions]);
        EQ.init(true);
    };

  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us `app.component.ts` code?

Comment: You can't use private API anymore  `import { SharedStylesHost } from '@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/shared_styles_host';` You can try `import { ɵSharedStylesHost } from '@angular/platform-browser';` instead

Comment: This worked! Now I have an follow error, but this is simple to fix. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear! Bitte!

Comment: @yurzui You should make your comment an answer. This worked for me too